# waypoint js click to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on a function with waypoint.js that takes the current div in the viewport and finds the next div when clicking a button.

Currently I’m getting a undefined value for the ‘next’. Not sure what could be wrong I guess the value can’t move from the waypoint function to the click function. Any help would be lovely.

```
$('.wrap').waypoint(function() {
var next = $(this).next();

$(".button").click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top }, 1000);
});
});
```

Comment: Show your HTML markup please.

Comment: could you make jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to chain it instead of doing this in the callback:

```
$('.wrap').waypoint().addBack(this).find(".button").click(function() {
     var next = $(this).closest('.wrap').next();
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

or could be something like this:

```
$('.wrap').waypoint().done(function(){
    $(this).find(".button").click(function() {
       var next = $(this).closest('.wrap').next();
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top }, 1000);
    });
});
```